# BeautifulSoup lowest common ancestor

Tags: python, algorithm, graph, beautifulsoup

Does the BeautifulSoup library for Python have any function that can take a list of nodes and return the lowest common ancestor?

If not, has any of you ever implemented such a function and care to share it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is what you want, with link1 being one element and link2 being another;

```
link_1_parents = list(link1.parents)[::-1]
link_2_parents = list(link2.parents)[::-1]

common_parent = [x for x,y in zip(link_1_parents, link_2_parents) if x is y][-1]

print common_parent
print common_parent.name
```

It'll basically walk both elements' parents from root down, and return the last common one.

Comment: Not quite. I want it to be able to work for a variable number of links, not just two, but I can edit that myself. Thank you.

Comment: As @Arthur pointed out, it only works if the 2 nodes are at the same depth.

Answer (score 4):

The accepted answer does not work if the distance from a tag in the input list to the lowest common ancestor is not the exact same for every nodes in the input.

It also uses every ancestors of each node, which is unnecessary and could be very expensive in some cases.

```
import collections
def lowest_common_ancestor(parents=None, *args):
    if parents is None:
        parents = collections.defaultdict(int)
    for tag in args:
        if not tag:
            continue
        parents[tag] += 1
        if parents[tag] == len(args):
            return tag
    return lowest_common_ancestor(parents, *[tag.parent if tag else None for tag in args])
```

Comment: It seems that the algorithm does not work for the case of a linear tree, a--b--c--d--e--f--g, LCA(b,g) should be b, but the algorithm will return a.

Comment: Thanks! you're perfectly right. I've corrected the code to correctly handle those cases

Comment: I don't think the code as it stands, or Iching Chang's answer, address Iching Chang's comment. The problem arises when we do `*[tag.parent if tag else None for tag in args]`, because we have moved *every* tag up one level in the tree. I used an approach inspired by Joachim Isaksson.

Answer (score 2):

Since Arthur's answer is not correct in some cases. I modified Arthur's answer, and give my answer. I have tested the code for LCA with two nodes as input.

```
import collections
def lowest_common_ancestor(parents=None, *args):
    if parents is None:
        parents = collections.defaultdict(int)
    for tag in args:
        parents[tag] += 1
        if parents[tag] == NUM_OF_NODES:
            return tag
    next_arg_list = [tag.parent for tag in args if tag.parent is not None]

    return lowest_common_ancestor(parents, *next_arg_list)
```

Call the function like:

```
list_of_tag = [tag_a, tag_b]
NUM_OF_NODES = len(list_of_tag)
lca = lowest_common_ancestor(None, *list_of_tag)
print(lca)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also compute XPaths of all elements and then use `os.path.commonprefix`. I am not familiar with BeautifulSoup, but in `lxml`, I have done this:

```py
def lowest_common_ancestor(nodes: list[lxml.html.HtmlElement]):
    if len(set(nodes)) == 1: # all nodes are the same
        return nodes[0]

    tree: lxml.etree._ElementTree = nodes[0].getroottree()
    xpaths = [tree.getpath(node) for node in nodes]
    lca_xpath = os.path.commonprefix(xpaths)
    lca_xpath = lca_xpath.rsplit('/', 1)[0] # strip partially matching tag names
    return tree.xpath(lca_xpath)[0]
```